# MaybeT/Maybe and IO: Failsafe reading of information

Tags: haskell, io, monad-transformers, option-type

I am trying to read information entered by the user and to parse it into the type `Person`, which uses the type `Gender`. To do so, I use this code:

```
data Person = Person String Int Gender String
data Gender = Male | Female | NotSpecified deriving Read

instance Show Gender where
    show Male = "male"
    show Female = "female"
    show NotSpecified = "not specified"

instance Show Person where
    show (Person n a g j) = "Person {name: " ++ n ++ ", age: " ++ show a ++ 
        ", gender: " ++ show g ++ ", job: " ++ j ++ "}"

readPersonMaybeT :: MaybeT IO ()
readPersonMaybeT = do
    putStrLn "Name?:"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Age?:"
    ageStr <- getLine
    putStrLn "Gender?:"
    genderStr <- getLine
    putStrLn "Job?:"
    job <- getLine

    let newPerson = Person name (read ageStr) (read genderStr) job
    putStrLn $ show newPerson
```

Now I would like to make this more failsafe - to achieve this I tried to use the MaybeT monad. using this, I got this code:

```
readPersonMaybeT :: MaybeT IO ()
readPersonMaybeT = do
    lift $ putStrLn "Name?:"
    name <- lift getLine
    lift $ putStrLn "Age?:"
    ageStr <- lift getLine
    lift $ putStrLn "Gender?:"
    genderStr <- lift getLine
    lift $ putStrLn "Job?:"
    job <- lift getLine

    let newPerson = Person name (read ageStr) (read genderStr) job
    lift $ putStrLn "show newPerson"
```

It get compiles/loaded by the GHCI, but when I try to execute the `readPersonMaybeT` function I get the error-message

> No instance for (Data.Functor.Classes.Show1 IO)
>     arising from a use of `print'
>   In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

How can I solve this issue? Writing this code, I used the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) about Monad Transformers.

EDIT: When I try to 'run' it with `runMaybeT` it gets executed, but it is not failsafe at all. Entering nonsense for the age for example still results in a output like

> Person {name: 85, age: *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse.

Comment: How did you 'execute' it? Did you use [`runMaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.html#runMaybeT) ?

Comment: No, I did not know, that I have to call runMaybeT... But I tried it now, and it did not solve the real problem (see the EDIT).

Comment: you should show us the definition of `Person`

Comment: You probably want to use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe)

Comment: ps. note that you're lifting every operation inside your `do` block. You're never doing anything in the actual `Maybe` monad.

Comment: Oh, this is true, but how can I read these values inside the ```Maybe``` monad? This does not work: ```gender <- maybeRead genderStr::Gender```, as I do not know, how to properly cast the read value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing the validation only after you have asked for all of the input, I would just use the IO monad and return a Maybe:

```
import Text.Read
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

askPerson :: IO (Maybe Person)
askPerson = do
  name <- putStr "Name? " >> getLine
  a <- putStr "Age? " >> getLine
  g <- putStr "Gender? " >> getLine
  return $ do age <- readMaybe a
              gender <- readMaybe g
              return $ Person name age gender
```

Note how we are using the Maybe monad in the `return` statement.

I would use MaybeT if you want to quit asking for input once they enter an invalid value --

```
askPersonT :: MaybeT IO Person
askPersonT = do
  name   <- liftIO $ putStr "Name? " >> getLine
  age    <- MaybeT $ fmap readMaybe $ putStr "Age? " >> getLine
  gender <- MaybeT $ fmap readMaybe $ putStr "Gender? " >> getLine
  return $ Person name age gender

doit = runMaybeT askPersonT
```

If the user enters an invalid age they won't be asked for a gender.

Comment: In the first, `return (Person <$> pure name <*> readMaybe a <*> readMaybe g)` is also idiomatic, I think. In the second we can also use applicative-style, but I actually prefer it as you wrote it since each line is already nontrivial.

Comment: The pure in your comment confuses me. Aren't we already in the right context from the usr of return and fmap?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I missed what was going on with the readMaybe calls.